# How to Split the day hour in shiftwise?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Can anyone say how to split the a day with 7 hours difference

Eg:

```
29/09/2018 00:00:00 -  29/09/2018 24:00:00
```

to

```
29/09/2018 07:00:00
29/09/2018 14:00:00
29/09/2018 21:00:00
```

Comment: I think you're asking for an hour-by-hour representation of an entire day (so 24 rows) with a column indicating where the person was in shift or off shift in that hour, but it's hard to tell. Please add code blocks (start each line with 4 spaces) not quite blocks, that show us your input data, your desired output and show us what you tried so far (so we know your table and column names if nothing else)

Comment: `12 + 7 != 20`.

Answer (score 2):

You could use CROSS APPLY to make one row with a date column appear 3 times, each with a different time. This can be done like this:

```
SELECT t.SomeDate, hrs.SplitDateTIme
FROM SomeTable t
CROSS APPLY (
    VALUES 
        (DATEADD(hour, 5, t.SomeDate)),
        (DATEADD(hour, 12, t.SomeDate)),
        (DATEADD(hour, 19, t.SomeDate))
) AS hrs(SplitDateTime);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are doing it in C# You can select a Start time of a day then add 7 hours to it

```
var date = DateTime.Now;
var date1 = date.AddHours(7);
var date2 = date1.AddHours(7);
```

Inform me is that what you want .